# so I was working on country code validation for poland and I am trying to creat

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on country code validation and I am working on poland here is the regex I have.

```
(([0|(\\+)](?=(48)))(?=(\d{11})))|(\d{9}))
```

My objective is to have it validate `048123456789` or `+48123456789` i.e. country code followed by nine digits or if the user enters a local number of just that,  nine digits. for example `123456789`.

Comment: What if it's a Polish person working in Germany, with a German number? Or a Czech one? Just saying - there's no bigger pain in the arse than a form that stupidly rejects my input just because I happen to be in a non-standard situation that the form's programmers didn't foresee. Are you sure this is necessary?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question?

Answer (score 5):

Your regex is very confusing... Maybe you could try a simpler:

```
^(?:[0+]48)?\d{9}$

^     // Matches beginning of string
[0+]  // Matches 0 or +
48    // Matches 48
\d{9} // Matches 9 digits
$     // Matches end of string
```

`(?:[0+]48)?` now is an optional group.

Comment: Nice and simple as always Jerry.

Comment: this regex will not match only 9 digits :/

Comment: @Sniffer See, I told you I missed something xD

Comment: @Darka I have missed that part. Thank you :)

Comment: Both you will be flaged as spammers :D

Comment: @Sniffer If you want. I can't tell you to vote or unvote posts ^^

Answer (score 2):

Why not use simply like this:

```
^((048|\+48|)\d{9})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this to match any kind of valid format

`^(((00|\+)48)?-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{2}|((00|\+)48)?-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3})$`

[image: RegEx]

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way to code it:

```
^([0+]48)?\d{9}$
```